# How to plot a histogram using grid graphics in R?

Tags: r, r-grid

I want to make a plot that is similar to `beanplot` or `violin` plot, but instead of the symmetric shapes, i want to plot two different distributions on the different sides of the center line. Something like figure 4 in this article [pdf]http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/c01/paper.

I want to use the `grid` graphics engine in `R`.   Any pointers will be useful.  I looked at the `lattice` package and the `histogram` function in `lattice` package, but that is not what i want to do.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.

Comment: @BenBarnes its on page six (there is only one plot on page six). It is indeed a boxplot alternative.

Comment: @Mattrition, Ooohh. That's an interesting plot. Ah, figure 4, not page 4.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what OP needs. It's clear from the paper that the graphic can be produced using `beanplot` and even gives the code to do so.

Comment: @BenBarnes probably my conception is wrong, may be it is an alternative to boxplot, but I think it is a very interesting plot, and i believe that my work can benefit from it.

Comment: @Sam What are you missing? The code to produce it is on page 6. Just plug in your own data.

Comment: And have a look at the `singer` dataset, in particular the `voice.part` column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reasonably easily get the half-violin plot with fairly simple modifications to the function, `panel.violin` in Sarkar's lattice package. There are four lines in that function that can be altered inside the `grid.polygon` call to change from "two-sided" density plotting to single sided density plotting. First `require(lattice)` and `require(grid)`. Then type `panel.violin`. I'll show you the "horizontal" alteration:

```
require(grid)
panel.violin2  <-  
    # snipped all the arguments and processing

       grid.polygon(x = c(dx.list[[i]] ), 
   # Notice I removed: ... ,rev(dx.list[[i]]) 
               y = c(2*dy.list[[i]]    ), default.units = "native", 
   # Removed: ...  , -rev(dy.list[[i]])
               name = trellis.grobname(identifier, type = "panel", 
                 group = group), gp = gpar(fill = col, col = border, 
                 lty = lty, lwd = lwd, alpha = alpha))
```

Also remove it from the corresponding section in the else{ ...} clause. Now you can run it with the example in help(panel.violin)

```
bwplot(voice.part ~ height, singer,
       panel = function(..., box.ratio) {
           panel.violin2(..., col = "transparent",
                        varwidth = FALSE, box.ratio = box.ratio)
           panel.bwplot(..., fill = NULL, box.ratio = .1)
       } )
```

[image]

If you wanted the density on the other side, all you would need to do would be remove the dx.list[[i]] and dy.list[[i]] and leave in the `rev(dx.list[[i]])` and `-rev(dy.list[[i]])`.